# The etymology of the word バックシャン

Tags: words, etymology, archaic-language

What is the etymology of the word バックシャン?
I understand it commonly refers to a woman beautiful only from behind. See this definition-

> 女性のうしろ姿が均整がとれて美しいこと。また、その女性。多く、前から見ると失望するような
>   場合にいう。

I understand the back/バック part, but is the シャン a version of ちゃん?
When did it come into common usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a compound of English "back" and German "schön" ("beautiful").

Comment: that's interesting- do u know how old it is?

Comment: Around 1927. It was popular during early Shōwa. Not used much anymore and many younger people will not understand it. By the way, an even older word is 一石六斗 (ikkoku rokuto), c. 1681.

Comment: Could you explain that one as well? I have no idea ~

Comment: Sure. When one is surprised, they say hatto (八斗) "oh". This 八斗 is 当字 (ateji) and also serves as unit of volume, or "8 to". A man sees a woman from behind and says hatto, surprised by her beauty. He then sees her face and again says hatto, this time surprised by the ugly face. Two hatto (8 to) is 16 hatto, which is equivalent to 1 石 (koku, a unit) and 6 斗 (to). Hence 一石六斗.

Comment: @yadokari, compare recent English slang term "[butterface](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/butterface)".

Comment: @Dono, do you have any citable sources for those dates?  I'd love to update the entries for [バックシャン](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%B3) and [一石六斗](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E7%9F%B3%E5%85%AD%E6%96%97#Japanese) on Wiktionary.